# My ListView has two types of views. How to manage?

Tags: android, android-listview

My events management app has two types of views in the  list view : a small simmple text view for not-so-important events and a complex view created with a `FrameLayout`.

in the `onCreateView()` of the adapter, I return these views depending upon the nature of the event.

```
if(convertView == null){
  if(important)
   // inflate the complex view
  else
   // inflate the simpler view
}
```

This is all good when `convertView` is null. Due to the view recycling in Android, it may happen that the `convertView` returned to me is recycled from the simpler view and I now have to display the larger view. One dumb solution is to inflate new views all the time. However, this will kill performance.

Another way is to have invisible `TextView`s in both of them (`visibility=gone`) with predefined values and depending on what value is in them, I can inflate the views. To me, this seems like a hack rather than a real solution.

**What is the right way to handle this situation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Due to the view recycling in Android, it may happen that the convertView returned to me is recycled from the simpler view and I now have to display the larger view.

Not if you override [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) and [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) in your adapter.

In your case:

- `getViewTypeCount()` would return 2
- `getItemViewType()` would return 0 or 1, where you return 0 for those positions that are one type of row, and return 1 for those positions that return the other type of row

Then, you are guaranteed that if `convertView` is not `null`, it is a row of the proper type.

Comment: I wish I could +5 this answer. This is so awesome. Thank you so much !   :) *PS +1 this answer if you are reading this*

Comment: Okay, read the documentation. Let's say that in my mind `0` is always the simpler view and `1` is the complex view. How do I set this mapping? :) A code snippet would be great !

Comment: Another typical fantastic CommonsWare answer.

Comment: @Little Child You would do something in getItemViewType() like if(myList.get(position).isImportant()) return 1; else return 0;

Comment: @LittleChild: Well, somehow, you must know for a given position whether it is the simpler or the complex one. I can't tell you how to do that, as that's tied to your object model. In your pseudocode above, that's how you derived the `important` flag. As zgc7009 indicates, your `getItemViewType()` would use that "important" concept to determine if it returns 0 or 1.

Comment: @CommonsWare All sorted out now ^_^. Just wanted to get some idea about `getItemViewType()`