# ListView scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

There are lots of questions here with the same title. I still couldn't find a solution. That's why I create a new one.
I have a navigation drawer and ListView inside of it. I have two custom views for items on this ListView: header and normal. I give the views for each item by considering their positions, but when I scroll it up and down, the views mix randomly. I kept my variables on a ViewHolder. It couldn't be a solution. My adapter below:

```
    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

        public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
            this.context = context;
            this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return navDrawerItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return navDrawerItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView icon;
            public TextView title, count;
        }

@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % 2;
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getType().equals("header")) {
                    row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_header, null, false);
                } else {
                    row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null, false);
                }
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.count = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.counter);

            holder.icon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
            holder.title.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

            if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
                holder.count.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
            } else {
                holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            row.setTag(holder);

            return row;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How many entries do you have in your list? You should be aware that the view holder pattern only makes sense if you have a lot of entries because it just speeds up the reuse of list view items a little by reducing the number of calls of findViewById(). Try without that pattern and only use it if you encounter performance issues.

Answer (score 9):

I have same issue when scroll quickly it alternate the vales of some item to others, just like background color of some items if changes randomly.
I solved this issue by searching a lot and find exact solution is just adding these two methods in your adapter if you are using ViewHolder in your adapter

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: More easy, imposible!, Thanks

Comment: This should be added to the Wiki. Can you explain why and how this works?

Comment: Yeah, because when this method will be override then listview will acknowledge the count of view type and it will stop duplicate the same item if already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ListView's` scrolling is laggy because

> you are creating ViewHolder's object everytime while you scroll that
>   ListView. So, your ViewHolder is useless.

try this code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getType().equals("header")) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_header, null, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            } else {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        holder.icon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.title.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
            holder.count.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        } else {
            holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your rewriting. But it's still the same. :(

Comment: When I scroll down, I take error below: 07-17 16:03:13.431: E/AndroidRuntime(13563): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.arkenus.fuar.adapters.NavDrawerListAdapter$ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

They wont mix if you override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in your adapter.

Once you do that, you are guaranteed that the the `convertView` provided is of the appropriate type.

[My ListView has two types of views. How to manage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717254/my-listview-has-two-types-of-views-how-to-manage)

Comment: I added these 2 methods which placed below in my adapter. But situation still the same.. I have edited my question with these methods.

Comment: It depends on your logic of `getItemViewType()`. If that is flawed, you will get mixed views. Read the answer I linked you to? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kaushik's answer but convertView needs to hold `viewHolder` not `position`, i have made changes see code..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getType().equals("header")) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_header, null, false);
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null, false);
        }
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        convertView.setTag(holder);  //as holder will be loaded at second iteration
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.icon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
    holder.title.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
        holder.count.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    } else {
        holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope it helps!...