# Android GridView, recycle two different cells?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView.  It is always two column.

For the first two cells at the top only, I have a different cell.

In the Apdater I do this...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (position<2) {
        // just return a new header cell - no need to try to be efficient,
        // there are only ever two of the header cells
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cell_header, null);
        return convertView;
        // you're completely done
    }

    // from here, we want only a normal cell...

    if (convertView == null) {
        // just make a new one
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.d.cell_normal, null);
    }

    // if you get to here, there's a chance it's giving us a header cell to recycle,
    // if so get rid of it

    int id = convertView.getId();
    if (id == R.id.id_cell_header) {
        Log.d("DEV", "We got a header cell in recycling - dump it");
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cell_normal, null);
    }

    ... populate the normal cell in the usual way

    return convertView;
    }
```

This works great.  Notice I just don't recycle the header cells. No problem since there is only two of them.

But what if you want a GridView with two totally different cells? (Imagine a GridView with say 50 of each type, all mixed together.)

I mean, both are the same size, but they are completely different, two different xml files, totally different layouts?

How do you "recycle both simultaneously"?

What's the deal with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24717323/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare - utterly magnificent, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not wanting to answer my own question, but

## with thanks to the always-amazing CommonsWare!...

here's exactly how you do it:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // we have two different types of cells, so return that number
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (..position should be a header-type cell..)
        return 1;       // 1 means to us "header type"
    else
        return 0;       // 0 means to us "normal type"
    // note the 0,1 are "our own" arbitrary index.
    // you actually don't have to use that index again: you're done.
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        if ( ..position should be a header-type cell.. )
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cell_header, null);
        else
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cell_normal, null);
    }

    if ( ..position should be a header-type cell.. ) {
        // .. populate the header type of cell ..
        // .. it WILL BE a header type cell ..
    }
    else {
        // .. populate the normal type of cell ..
        // .. it WILL BE a normal type cell ..
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

It's a case of "Good Android" ... beautiful, lovely stuff.